# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyonmttok ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyonmttok

Tags: python, tokenize

I'm unable to install package pyonmttok on windows. Can someone please help regarding this?

I tried the commands `pip install pyonmttok` as well as `python m -pip install pyonmttok` got the same error, also tried this on both ***python 3.6*** and ***python 3.9***

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the "pip" command ?  Please show commands you wrote about your trial to solve this problem, and give specific error messages or details you would like help about. So we can copy paset and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I used both commands  "pip install pyonmttok" as well as "python m -pip install pyonmttok", got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module that you're trying to install has not been released by the developers (OpenNMT) for Windows. It only works for Ubuntu(or Linux in general). You can check the issue on their github [here](https://github.com/OpenNMT/Tokenizer/issues/118)